# What does this line of assembly do?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have this line of assembly:

```
cmpb   $0x0,(%rax,%rcx,1)
```

Now, according to the references out there, `cmpb` does an immediate compare of two bytes. So it compares 0 with `(%rax,%rcx,1)`. Can somebody explain what this second argument is / does?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the AT&T syntax for

```
cmp BYTE PTR [rax+rcx*1], 0
```

So it computes the address using `rax + rcx`, dereference it to obtain a **b**yte, and then  **c**o**mp**are it with the number 0.

Answer (score 5):

The general syntax for this type of memory operand is:

```
disp(base,offset,mult)
```

which gives you the address:

```
base + disp + offset*mult
```

So in your case (disp is 0), `cmpb` compares 0 and the value stored at:

```
%rax + (%rcx * 1)
```